# How to build a Perl multidimensional array or hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a set of CSV values like this:

```
device name, CPU value, frequency of CPU value, CPU in percentage
```

For example

```
router1,5,10,4
router1,5,1,5
router2,5,10,4
router2,5,2,5
router3,4,5,6
router3,7,6,5
```

I need to form a data structure like this:

```
array = {
    router1 => [5,10,4],[5,1,5],
    router2 => [5,10,4],[5,2,5],
    router3 => [4,5,6],[7,6,5]
}
```

I need help in forming this data structure in Perl.

I have tried visualizing how to do this but am unable to do so. I would appreciate any help on this.

The end goal for me is to convert this into a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. It uses the `DATA` file handle so that I could embed the data in the program itself. I have used `to_json` from the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) module to format the hash as JSON data. The statement `$_ += 0 for @values` converts the contents of `@values` from string to to numeric, to avoid quotation marks in the resultant JSON data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($device, @values) = split /,/;
  $_ += 0 for @values;
  push @{ $data{$device} }, \@values;
}

print to_json(\%data, { pretty => 1, canonical => 1 });

__DATA__
router1,5,10,4
router1,5,1,5
router2,5,10,4
router2,5,2,5
router3,4,5,6
router3,7,6,5
```

**output**

```
{
   "router1" : [
      [
         5,
         10,
         4
      ],
      [
         5,
         1,
         5
      ]
   ],
   "router2" : [
      [
         5,
         10,
         4
      ],
      [
         5,
         2,
         5
      ]
   ],
   "router3" : [
      [
         4,
         5,
         6
      ],
      [
         7,
         6,
         5
      ]
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution which prints desired JSON object.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($device, @cpu_values) = split(/,/, $line);
  my $cpu_token = join(",", @cpu_values);
  $hash{$device} .= '[' . $cpu_token . '], ';
}

my @devices = keys %hash;

print "array = { \n";
foreach  (sort @devices) {

    print "$_ => [$hash{$_}]\n";

} 
print "}\n";

__DATA__
router1,5,10,4
router1,5,1,5
router2,5,10,4
router2,5,2,5
router3,4,5,6
router3,7,6,5
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you need to use references in the way of anonymous arrays and hashes to make multidimensional arrays, arrays of arrays, hashes containing hashes and anywhere in between. [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) should cover how to accomplish what you are trying to do. Here is an example I wrote the other day that could help explain as well:

```
print "\nFun with multidimensional arrays\n";
my @myMultiArray = ([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]);

for my $a (@myMultiArray){
    for my $b (@{$a}){
        print "$b\n";
    }
}

print "\nFun with multidimensional arrays containing hashes\nwhich contains an anonymous array\n";
my @myArrayFullOfHashes = (
    {'this-key'=>'this-value','that-key'=>'that-value'},
    {'this-array'=>[1,2,3], 'this-sub' => sub {return 'hi'}},
);

for my $a (@myArrayFullOfHashes){
    for my $b (keys %{$a}){
        if (ref $a->{$b} eq 'ARRAY'){
            for my $c (@{$a->{$b}}){
                print "$b.$c => $c\n";
            }
        } elsif ($a->{$b} =~ /^CODE/){
            print "$b => ". $a->{$b}() . "\n";
        } else {
            print "$b => $a->{$b}\n";
        }
    }
}
```